# What is the "Will be announced (all times Eastern US)" event on arXiv's announcement schedule?

Tags: arxiv

I see that there is a "Will be announced (all times Eastern US)" event on [arXiv's announcement schedule](https://info.arxiv.org/help/availability.html):

| Submissions received between (all times Eastern US) | Will be announced (all times Eastern US) | Mailed to subscribers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday 14:00 – Tuesday 14:00 | Tuesday 20:00 | Tuesday night / Wednesday morning |
| Tuesday 14:00 – Wednesday 14:00 | Wednesday 20:00 | Wednesday night / Thursday morning |
| Wednesday 14:00 – Thursday 14:00 | Thursday 20:00 | Thursday night / Friday morning |
| Thursday 14:00 – Friday 14:00 | Sunday 20:00 | Sunday night / Monday morning |
| Friday 14:00 – Monday 14:00 | Monday 20:00 | Monday night / Tuesday morning |

What is it? Is it when submitters are emailed their arXiv paper IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "Announcement" means the moment at which the preprint becomes publicly available under a permanent arXiv ID and URL.

Submitters receive a notification email, including the ID, shortly after the announcement.  I checked a notification email for a preprint from a few months ago (submitted by a coauthor), and it was sent out by arXiv at 20:26 EDT on a Sunday.  The preprint had been submitted on the preceding Thursday at 16:32 EDT, so that fits with the time window shown in the table.

arXiv offers [announcement email lists](https://info.arxiv.org/help/subscribe.html), one per subject class (e.g. `math.DG`), to which anyone can subscribe.  These emails are sent out within a few hours after the announcements each day, which is what the third column indicates.

Comment: That's mostly correct. The 20:00 is the time that the mailing *begins* and the time at which the permanent ids are assigned. When there were only a handful of daily submissions to any given area, it would be more or less instantaneous. The longest I've seen in the logs is over an hour and a half, but usually about 40 minutes.

Comment: (but I'm splitting hairs beyond a pedants wish here)

Comment: @Jake thanks, that's great to know, I was wondering exactly about that point,  as I received the notification email at 6 PM PDT a few days ago, and I was wondering if the arXiv's announcement schedule was in ET, EDT or EST. You are welcome to share your experience in an answer, as comments may be removed at any time.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Last week there was a problem where the automatic emails weren't going out because of a [DDOS attack against arXiv](https://blog.arxiv.org/2023/09/11/arxiv-org-is-experiencing-a-ddos-attack/). The papers are queued for announcement at 8pm Eastern (EST/EDT just depends on the date), so if you received it late, it may have been for that reason, rather than a change in the system.

Comment: @Jake Thanks. I have no idea who would want to DDoS arXiv.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Elsevier, maybe....?  Or, more likely, someone disgruntled about their manuscript being rejected.